# Function for "evenly distributing" a sequential number across the space of possible values

Tags: hash, sequential

I need to store a bunch of entities in Google AppEngine (or you can think of any other hash table) under keys that I need to create myself from a sequential input.

As an example, let's say I only deal with keys with a length of one decimal digit. Then I need to store one entity for key '0', one for key '1', one for key '2', and so forth.

The problem is that if I just use this increasing sequence directly as the keys, it will lead to all entities being physically stored very close to each other, which can cause severe performance issues. [Details here](http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/). For a general hash-table, you can think of all entries not being evenly spread over all buckets, but instead clustering in just a few buckets, which also leads to performance degradation for look-ups, etc.

So, I'm looking for some function to "re-distribute" my values more evenly across the space of available values.

To stay with the example of single-digit-keys, I could just create a table that contains a random permutation of all possible values, like [5,9,2,4,1,8,0,6,3,7] and index into that. Then, when I store entries 0, 1, and 2, which would be located right next to each other, I would instead assign keys 5, 9, and 2 that are more spread out across servers or hash-buckets.

But I need to find a way to do this for 156-bit numbers, in which case a table with a random permutation of all values is not feasible.

I have two requirements:

- Every possible 156-bit number must be mapped to **exactly one** value (up to 160-bit is OK). No collisions allowed
- This should be computationally cheap

I found one way to do it: Simply "encrypt" my value with [SHACAL-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHACAL) or some other 160bit cipher. But this seems like way too much computational effort for what I'm trying to achieve. Is there maybe some pseudo-random function that I can use with my value as the seed? Would they be guaranteed collision free?

Comment: Lets assume you want to do this for numbers from 0 to 255. Here are values 'number':'hash' 0:0, 1:128, 2:64, 3:192, 4:32, 5:96, 6:160, 7:224, is this what you want?

Comment: @OndrejPetrzilka So, basically reversing the order of the bits in the number? We discussed this idea earlier in G_G's answer below. I think it might be a useful one, just haven't had time to follow through with it yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the discrete logarithm which gives you a perfect deterministic permutation of all your array positions. However, the permutation is one-way: you can't retrieve the original position of your new i-th array position without resorting to brute force (or re-doing the permutation in the allowed direction)

OR

if you don't care about extra space you could store pair `<value-originalindex>` and place them completely at random (using some PRNG function) reiterating in case of collision (or taking note of the already used places). Now the pairs are distributed evenly. Retrieving the i-th element takes O(N) where N is the number of places. That's the price for this algorithm.

OR

take only few random bits of your 156-bit values and use them to form, let's say, a 12bit unsigned index. Use this index to select the k-th bucket from you final space (your space is partitioned in 2^12 buckets). Values will tend to aggregate only if they share the same 12 bit random bits which is very unlikely if you pick them carefully...  Use the remaining 156-12=143 bit to offset inside buckets.

OR

create a fixed random permutation of your 156 bits.

Comment: I was thinking that, but doing that with 156-bit numbers sounds even harder (i.e. slower) than SHACAL... Or is there some trick? (Not being able to retrieve the original value is OK)

Comment: unfortunately any standard hashing function suffer from collision, that's the pigeon principle at it's finest :-) How large is your array?

Comment: 156-bit value in, up to 160-bit values out. So a unique mapping should definitely be possible.

Comment: another solution added to my answer

Comment: :) Unfortunately, I do care about space... That's where the 160-bit limit comes from (no extra bytes beyond what I need to store 156-bits)

Comment: what about a probabilistic approach? you hash your entities and in case of collision rehash it until it settle to a free place. I call it probabilistic because in theory it could be that you keep rehashing forever, in any practical scenario this will never happen

Comment: The problem is that the reason for using the sequential value as a key rather than having the database create a unique one for me is to detect duplicates, so collisions are unfortunately really not acceptable...

Comment: just another approach in my answer... have a look at it

Comment: Interesting... Definitely a +1 for this one... :) To generalize: Basically, I just re-shuffle the bits in the value cleverly to move the least significant ones (i.e. the ones that change frequently due to the increment) into more significant positions. Maybe if I just reverse the bit-order of the number? That could be all I need. I wonder how that would fare in a Java HashTable...

Comment: take the last approach to the extreme. Create a fixed random permutation of your 156 bits. That's all you need. Sequential binary counting (0,1,2,3,4....) will be transformed into a scattered, collision-free, pattern (523413,213534467,86732423233, etc...). The point is, don't swap least significant bits with most significant ones, just create a random permutation of your 156 bits.

Comment: I think it might actually be better to specifically pick the permutation to maximize distribution of the values across buckets...

Comment: I mean, remove the bucket thing altogether and just randomly shuffle your 156 bits (example: bit0 -> bit102, bit1 -> bit45, bit2 -> bit71 etc..)

Comment: Understood. That might not be the optimal solution, though, as, in the worst case, you could end up with a "random" swapping that moves every bit back to where it started (or close to it), in which case we didn't win anything (much). I think optimizing it for the hash-table at hand might be best. So, for the AppEngine data-store, I would reverse the bits, since it sorts (and distributes across buckets) in lexical order, while for a Java HashTable key, I would actually keep the number as is since it uses the natural ordering of the keys (bucket = key % bucket-count).

Comment: Leaves just one problem: Bit shuffling is not the most efficient operation either... In fact, it's so nasty that people have written code-generators for it: http://programming.sirrida.de/calcperm.php

Comment: you don't have to compute the shuffling every time. You pick a shuffle pattern at random and stick to it. You must use that shuffle permutation every time! So the problem is all about bitwise binary arithmetic (and, or, shifting and such...)

Comment: Absolutely, but it takes quite a bit of operations to compute the permutation... To reverse the bits of an integer takes 24 binary operations: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.reverse%28int%29 Not sure how much reversing a 156-bit number would take, but there might be a cheaper way out there to achieve what I need without bitwise operations...